# Finished Activity starting up on resuming the app from background

Tags: android

I have a peculiar problem. I have an `Activity A`, from which, after user logs in, I finish `Activity A` and start `Activity B`. I have a `RecyclerView` in `Activity B`, which starts fetching the data from my database. Now the issue is that if within 2-3 seconds of starting `Activity B`, I put the app in background by pressing android's back button and then fetch the app from menu, my app is again displaying the already finished `Activity A`.

My launcher Activity is Main, where the app decides whether to open `Activity A` or `Activity B` based on whether user has already logged in or not. I tried changing order of activities and checking cache values etc, but I am totally stumped. `Activity A` is simply popping up on resumption.

Please let me know if anyone has idea as to why this might be occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you press the back button, Android would assume you want to exit the app. So when you open the app again, it will start from the beginning.

By checking whether or not user has logged in, you can decide to show Activity A or B. Without being able to check your code, it's difficult to say where stops you doing that. One possible solution is that save user login status in **SharedPreferences** so you can check if user has logged in when the app starts.

Comment: Given that MainActivity is the launcher activity in my app, so I take it that Android should start from that, but when I debug the code, MainActivity is not started but straightaway Activity A is started. I am already saving login status in sharedpreferences, so I guess the best solution at this point would be to add the same condition that I have in MainActivity to Activity A and based on that start Activity B immediately.